# Error while building gcc cross compiler for i686-elf on ubuntu16.04

Tags: c, gcc

[bash screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lvsu.png)

```
/osd-src/gcc-6.1.0/isl/include/isl/ctx.h:108:8: error: attempt to use poisoned "malloc"
        malloc(size)))
        ^
/home/desai/osd-src/gcc-6.1.0/isl/include/isl/ctx.h:112:8: error: attempt to use poisoned "realloc"
        realloc(ptr,size)))
```

this is the error msg while i am performing this command

```
$ make all-target-libgcc
```

I am following this link for installation http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler

I am new to Linux and stack-overflow, guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code (or included code ) there is a [poison pragma](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/cpp/Pragmas.html) which was put in place to prevent you from using these identifiers.

Comment: Thank You for replying.
There was version of ILS-0.12 which was not supporting with cloog-v0.18 . I updated new version and reinstalled it. Works now..

Answer (score 0):

There was version of ILS-0.12 which was not supported with cloog-v0.18 . I updated new version and reinstalled it. Works now.